# How to programmatically import plug-ins and fragments from jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have some plug-ins and fragments exported in some jar files. I need to programmatically import those plug-ins and fragments as it is usually done through GUI by using `File --> Import --> Plug-in Development --> Plug-ins and Fragments` so I have these in my current workspace. I have read some posts related to import projects (i.e. by exploiting `.project`) but in this case I only have jar files.

Snippets and/or hints will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Source-Code of Eclipse how it's done. - Open the wizard that implements the requested functionality open Plugin-Spy (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and jump into the source code (in your case a good starting point would be `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.wizards.imports.PluginImportWizardDetailedPage`)

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunatly, I had a look of the classes PluginImportWizardDetailedPage, PluginImportWizard, and WizardDialog but I actually did not get the way to go. I expected to do that in a few lines of code by selecting the jar files, create a project and open it. Is it possible or it is necessary to follow more complex steps?